# What happens if two dart asynchronous functions try to add to the same List concurrently?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, concurrency, async-await

Does dart handle the case in which two different calls of an asynchronous function try to add two (or more) objects to a List at the same time? If it does not is there a way for me to handle this?

I do not need those two new objects to be inserted in a particular order because I take care of that later on, I only wandered what happens in that unlikely but still possible case

Comment: dart code executes in one, single thread so: yes those `async` functions can add it to one linst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering if there's any kind of locking necessary to prevent race conditions in the `List` data structure itself, no.  As [pskink noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165452/what-happens-if-two-dart-asynchronous-functions-try-to-add-to-the-same-list-conc#comment106415150_60165452), each Dart [isolate](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) runs in its own thread, and as the "isolate" name implies, memory is not shared.  Two operations therefore cannot both be actively updating a `List` at the same time.  Once all asynchronous operations complete, your `List` will contain all of the added items but not with any guaranteed ordering.

If you need to prevent asynchronous operations from being interleaved, you could use [`package:pool`](https://pub.dev/packages/pool).